# AWS Athena string with ddmmyyyy to date time

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

i have 2 columns in my athena table that comes like i.e 20230501 and 183434 values.Each row has diferent values . I would like to have a date type column 2023-05-01 or separated by / as long as its date format. Also,i would like to have 18:34:34 as timestamp type column.
Than you very much

i tried a numerous different querys but didnt workout such as:

```
SELECT date_parse(your_column, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date_column FROM your_table;
```

Also tried glue jobs.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `date_parse` function is the format of the input, not the output — ie. it should correspond to `20230501` not `2023-05-01`.

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT date_parse(your_column, '%Y%m%d') AS date_column FROM your_table;
```

Comment: I get a error saying: Queries of this type are not supported